# Simple yield from ES6 generator when library uses callback

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

Consider this generator that uses asynch request (ie: superagent):

```
static * findOne (model, id) {
  const url = [this.host, model].join('/')
  let res
  yield request
    .get(url)
    .end((err, resp) => {
      res = resp
    })
  return res
}
```

This feels very clumsy ... setting res, then updating its value after async operation. Is there a cleaner, tighter way to do this?

I know I could use a promise and yield it ... but seems not to add value and only means I have more code and nesting in the promises function argument

I know I can't yield in the end() chainable ...

Open to suggestions ...

Comment: do you have to use superagent? what framework is the generator getting plugged into?

Comment: What (kind of yieldable) does `.end(…)` return? Looks very much like a promise already.

Comment: I don't have to use superagent, but I prefer the simplicity, consistency and concise nature of its api. The value yielded by the return is a http response object

Answer (score 0):

For those that find this question, it looks like you  can simply do this:

```
  static * findMany (model, query) {
    const url = ['http://localhost:3333', model].join('/')
    yield request
      .get(url)
      .end()
  }
```

... as superagent supports yielding already and returns the response object